# Change an Array of Dates to an Array of Strings in Different Date Format - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, date, datepicker

I seem to be going around in circles on this one. Essentially, I have an array of strings that are in the following format ["2017-08-24", "2017-08-29", "2017-09-13". I have another array that is comprised of dates in the conventional Date format.

I need to convert this array of dates (that are in the standard Date format) into the same format as my string array so that I can check them against each other.

Here is my code so far:

```
var stringDates = ["2017-08-24", "2017-09-11", "2017-12-05", ...]
var datesArray = [Wed Aug 23 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST), Thu Aug 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST), Fri Aug 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST), Sat Aug 26 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)]
```

Does anyone have any experience with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a standard date to your format by doing the following:

```
var myDate = new Date(yourNormalDateHere) 
var formatted = (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + myDate.getDate() + "-" + myDate.getFullYear()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function to convert the Date to a String:

```
function dateToString(date){
  return date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate();
}
```

Now just push it to your array of dates:

```
between.push(dateToString(date));
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. My Between array needs to have every item changed to the date format and string type that I need and then placed back into an array. That's what I'm struggling with, to do this for all items in the array...

Comment: @dreamkiller Then you should [**edit your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45824960/edit) and add this information there. Note that you don't need to add a **edit** or **update** section: you can reword the entire question if needed, if that makes things more clear.

Comment: Could you please share how your array looks like now and what is the expected result?

Comment: Like @hugo said, this to be more specific with your questions. Somethinglike: I.e I have this array: [..... , ....., ... ] and need to turn it into [..... , ....., ... ].

Comment: Any thoughts Mauricio?

Comment: could you put also the expected result array?